# Is it possible to extract Dom Elements from htmlentities() function in php?

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I appreciate the time you take to try and help me with my question.
So what i am doing is trying an html parser from a link. So I use curl first to link to the website then I convert it into htmlentities() so it doesn't load on the page so I get a string from that then i use the DOM object to extract the  tag from. I checked different methods for a parser on google search so i learned a little bit about it then i execute my script but the problem is that the string is getting saved as textCont and not as a real html document so i would like to know how can convert htmlentities string into a real dom document and extract elements from it ?
[the image of the var_dump is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Zmq.jpg)
here is my script:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/world/2021/02/17/dubai-princess-sheikha-latifa-says-she-hostage-after-flee-attempt/6778014002/?utm_source=feedblitz&utm_medium=FeedBlitzRss&utm_campaign=usatodaycomworld-topstories');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$htmlentities = htmlentities($result);
// I added the code here 
$htmlDom = new DOMDocument();
$htmlDom->loadHTML($htmlentities);
$htmlDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$styles = $htmlDom->getElementsByTagName('style');

foreach ($styles as $style) {
    
    $item = $style->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

    //echo the values 
    echo '1: '.$item->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
    echo '2: '.$item->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
    echo '3: '.$item->item(2)->nodeValue;  
 }
```

**EDIT:**

what i added next to the code is this:

```
$htmlentities = htmlentities($result);
$htmlentities = str_replace("&quot;",'"', $htmlentities);
$htmlentities = str_replace("&#039;","'", $htmlentities);
$htmlentities = str_replace("&lt;","<", $htmlentities);
$htmlentities = str_replace("&gt;",">", $htmlentities);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$htmlDom = new DOMDocument();
$htmlDom->loadHTML($htmlentities);

libxml_clear_errors();
var_dump($htmlDom);
```

Comment: Why are you applying `htmlentities()` to your downloaded data? That is specifically intended to prevent HTML being interpreted as HTML. And having applied it, you're then unpicking bits of it with `str_replace()`. That's just odd.

Comment: because i am trying to convert to a html string but i you have another solution please let me know

Comment: I don't have a different solution for that web site since most of the content is loaded by scripts after the initial page load. Take a look at the page source and you'll see that there are no `<td>` elements in it at all. Whatever it is you're trying to scrape, you're going to need to be a lot more sophisticated about it.

Comment: I see, thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular what I am trying to do is prevent the page from rendering that is why i put htmlentities() when i echo $result so is there a way to prevent the page from rendering ?